# How to map output of Execute R Script to second port in ML Studio using maml.mapOutputPort

Tags: r, ml-studio

Execute R Script box in ML Studio has two output ports. How does one send data to the second output port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently ML Studio does not support the mapping of output data to a second port. This can be verified by executing the following code:

```
# Map 1-based optional input ports to variables
dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1) # class: data.frame

# Select data.frame to be sent to the output Dataset port
maml.mapOutputPort("dataset1", 1);
maml.mapOutputPort("dataset1", 2);
```

which returns

```
---------- Start of error message from R ----------
Error: At this time, there is only 1 output dataset port that can be mapped. Please provide 1 as the portNumber
```

As a workaround you can output your `data.frame` with an additional column labeling which output set is intended. Then `Clean Missing Data` with action `Remove entire row` can be used to truncate the data to the correct output and `Select Columns in Dataset` and be used to remove the extraneous column.

Comment: Its 2020, and this is still not supported.